# Gcc-4.8 compilation issue in ubuntu-20.04lts docker

Tags: docker, gcc, compiler-errors, ubuntu-20.04, gcc4.8

I'm trying to compile `gcc-4.8` in ubuntu-20.04 docker using below dockerfile.

```yaml
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:20.04
..............
...................
........................
## Get gcc 4.8.5 and build it
RUN wget http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz \
&& tar xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && \
cd gcc-4.8.5 && \
./contrib/download_prerequisites && \
cd .. && mkdir gccbuild && cd gccbuild && \
../gcc-4.8.5/configure \
--prefix="/opt/gcc" \
--enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix \
--enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
--enable-languages="c,c++" --disable-bootstrap \
&& make all && make install
```

When i build the image, `make all` shows below error message.

> In file included from ../../gcc-4.8.5/gcc/cp/except.c:1008:
> cfns.gperf:101:1: error: 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*,
> unsigned int)' redeclared inline with 'gnu_inline' attribute
> cfns.gperf:26:14: note: 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned
> int)' previously declared here cfns.gperf:26:14: warning: inline
> function 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)' used but
> never defined make[2]: Leaving directory '/gccbuild/gcc' make[2]: ***
> [Makefile:1059: cp/except.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/gccbuild' make[1]: *** [Makefile:3920: all-gcc] Error 2 make: ***
> [Makefile:865: all] Error 2 The command '/bin/sh -c wget
> http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && tar
> xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && cd gcc-4.8.5 && sed -i 's/ftp/http/g'
> contrib/download_prerequisites && ./contrib/download_prerequisites &&
> cd .. && mkdir gccbuild && cd gccbuild && ../gcc-4.8.5/configure
> --prefix="/opt/gcc" --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-languages="c,c++" --disable-bootstrap && make all && make install' returned a non-zero code: 2

I need this particular OS and GCC version to build our old source code. Looking for any suggestions to install `Gcc-4.8` in ubuntu-20.04-LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler are you using to bootstrap gcc-4.8.5? Does the `configure` fail, or is it `make all` ?

Comment: @James McPherson, `make all` fails.

Comment: That's useful to know, what's _more_ useful though is to tell us what compiler (+ version) are you using to bootstrap it?

Comment: @JamesMcPherson, Compiler version - `GNU Make 4.2.1`.

Comment: No, that's the version of Make, which is a different utility entirely. What's the output from `gcc -v`

Comment: It is `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`